# Move certain subfolders to another folder

Tags: find

I have a main folder with several subfolders (that have a numbered name format), and i need to retrieve just the ones that start with 6, to a folder. Can i make this recursevely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have this structure:

```
$ mkdir 1dir 2dir 6dir 6anotherdir 1dir/666dir ../targetdir
$ touch 6file somefile 1dir/a 2dir/b 6dir/c 1dir/666dir/d
$ tree -F . ../targetdir
.
├── 1dir/
│   ├── 666dir/
│   │   └── d
│   └── a
├── 2dir/
│   └── b
├── 6anotherdir/
├── 6dir/
│   └── c
├── 6file
├── somefile
../targetdir                                                                                                                     

5 directories, 6 files
```

Then we can move the directories starting with `6` like this (assuming the `targetdir` is your target directory we created a level above the current one):

```
find . -name "6*" -type d -prune -exec mv "{}" ../targetdir/ \;
```

Result:

```
tree -F . ../targetdir/
.
├── 1dir/
│   └── a                                                                                                                        
├── 2dir/                                                                                                                        
│   └── b                                                                                                                        
├── 6file                                                                                                                        
└── somefile                                                                                                                     
../targetdir/                                                                                                                
├── 666dir/                                                                                                                      
│   └── d                                                                                                                        
├── 6anotherdir/                                                                                                                 
└── 6dir/                                                                                                                        
    └── c

5 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.This will copy the folders and their contents, correct?

Comment: Replace `-exec` with `-ok` to confirm each `mv` command before running it.

Comment: @Celso.Baia Yes, as you can see from the example, it moved the files `c` and `d` with the parent folder. The `mv` command does this.

Comment: This command will give `no such file or directory errors`.

Comment: @Flimm Yes it will. But it still works. I'm still finding out why it prints these errors (as listing the mv-commands will not list commands to produce these errors). Any clue?

Comment: `find . -type d -name '6*' -prune -exec mv "{}" /TARGET/ \;` will do what you want, as long as /TARGET/ is not a subdirectory of the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -name '6*' -prune -exec mv "{}" DESTINATION_FOLDER/
```

The `-prune` option is required to stop `find` from recursing into directories that will no longer be there after being moved.

Comment: Glad you posted this as an answer, because [that comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251273/move-certain-subfolders-to-another-folder/251279#comment313574_251279) actually needed upvotes. Now also implemented in my answer.